# When to divide by n when calculating mean squared prediction error

Tags: regression, predictive-models, least-squares

The following slides are from [here](http://dept.stat.lsa.umich.edu/%7Ekshedden/Courses/Regression_Notes/prediction.pdf).

[image]
[image]

In the first slide, it says that the mean squared prediction error for OLS regression is $E||y^* - \hat{y}^*||^2=tr((X^{*'}X^*\Sigma_{\hat{\beta}}) + n^* \sigma^2$.

At the beginning of the next slide, it says that the mean squared prediction error is now $tr((X^{*'}X^*/n^*) \Sigma_{\hat{\beta}}) + \sigma^2$?

Why are the two equations different, and when should I divide by $n^*$ when calculating the MSPE?

Comment: You are overinterpreting the first slide: it only announces it will *derive* the MSPE. It never states the first formula is the MSPE.  But it doesn't even matter, does it, because minimizing one is tantamount to minimizing the other.

Comment: I see. Is there a name for the quantity in the first slide $E||y^* - \hat{y}^*||$ if not the MSPE?

Comment: Expected (Euclidean) norm of the residuals would be one lengthy but accurate and clear term for it.